# Is there a PHP library for email address validation?

Tags: php, email, open-source, email-validation

I need to validate the email address of my users. Unfortunately, making a validator that [conforms to standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) is hard.

[Here](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is an example of a regex expression that tries to conform to the standard.

Is there a PHP library (preferably, open-source) that validates an email address?

Comment: are we talking e-mails or email addresses?

Comment: I meant email address. I've corrected my question to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a library in google code: http://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/

Are there any others?

Comment: I use its predecessor in several projects and haven't had any issues so far. I say go for it.

Comment: The link still works, but perhaps it is time for [an update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/161344/edit)? It may or may not have moved somewhere else, like GitHub. But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 16):

Have you looked at [PHP's filter_ functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)? They're not perfect, but they do a fairly decent job in my experience.

Example usage (returns boolean):

`filter_var($someEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: I'm coding up a simple (non-Enterprise) app that needs a basic validator. While FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL doesn't seem to fully implement the spec -- for example, it fails some of the tests at http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/rfc822.phps -- it seems to be "good enough" for my current needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK, the only good way to validate an e-mail is to to send an e-mail and see if user goes back to the site using a link in this e-mail. That's what lot of sites do.

As you point out with the link to the well known mammoth regex, validating all forms of e-mail address is hard, near to impossible. It is so easy to do it wrong, even for trivial style e-mails (I found too many sites rejecting caps in e-mail addresses! And most old regexes reject TLDs of more than 4 letters!).

AFAIK, "Jean-Luc B. O'Grady"@example.com and e=m.c^2@[82.128.45.117] are both valid addresses... While I-Made-It-Up@Absurd-Domain-Name.info is likely to be invalid.

So somehow, I would just check that we have something, a unique @, something else, and go with it: it would catch most user errors (like empty field or user name instead of e-mail address).
If user wants to give a fake address, it would just give something random looking correct (see@on.tv or bill.gates@microsoft.com). And no validator will catch typos (jhon.b@example.com instead of john.b@example.com).

If one really want to validate e-mails against full RFC, I would advise to use regexes to split around @, then check separately local name and domain name. Separate case of local name starting with " from other cases, etc. Separate case of domain name starting with [ from other cases, etc. Split problem in smaller specific domains, and use regexes only on a well defined, simpler cases.
This advice can be applied to lot of regex uses, of course...

Comment: That is a valid answer and what I would normally do. But for this particular client, I needed a way to check if an email is valid.

The alternative to email validation is asking the user to input their emails twice, which I strongly disprove of. Hopefully, I can convince them not to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with double-entry?  It's a quick, cheap, and easy way to ensure that the user didn't fat-finger their email address while typing it in.  If you *really* need to verify that an email address has a valid format, Dominic's answer (and linked site) seems to contain the most comprehensive information I've seen yet.

Comment: @afrazier: "What's wrong with double-entry?"
Well, if people do like me, they just copy/paste the first entry into the second one, so the benefit is null...

Answer (score 10):

[UPDATED] I've collated everything I know about email address validation here: http://isemail.info, which now not only validates but also diagnoses problems with email addresses. I agree with many of the comments here that validation is only part of the answer; see my essay at [http://isemail.info/about](http://isemail.info).

I've now collated test cases from Cal Henderson, Dave Child, Phil Haack, Doug Lovell and RFC 3696. 158 test addresses in all.

I ran all these tests against all the validators I could find. The comparison is here: http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail

I'll try to keep this page up-to-date as people enhance their validators. Thanks to Cal, Dave and Phil for their help and co-operation in compiling these tests and constructive criticism of [my own validator](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/source/browse/trunk/is_email.php).

People should be aware of the [errata against RFC 3696](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696) in particular. Three of the canonical examples are in fact invalid addresses. And the maximum length of an address is 254 or 256 characters, **not** 320.

Comment: Thanks for doing this; it's awesome to have real data to work off of, instead of just speculation. Can you also include the other libraries mentioned on this page?

Answer (score 8):

[Cal Henderson](http://www.iamcal.com/) (of Flickr) wrote an [RFC822 compliant email address matcher](http://www.iamcal.com/publish/articles/php/parsing_email), with an explanation of the RFC and code utilizing the RFC to match email addresses.  I've been using it for quite some time now with no complaints.

> RFC822 (published in 1982) defines,
>   amongst other things, the format for
>   internet text message (email)
>   addresses. You can find the RFC's by
>   googling - there's many many copies of
>   them online. They're a little terse
>   and weirdly formatted, but with a
>   little effort we can seewhat they're
>   getting at.

... Update ...

As [Porges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10311/porges) pointed out in the comments, the library on the link is outdated, but that page has a link to an [updated version](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/).

Comment: Worth noting that RFC822 is ancient, as the quote identifies. In fact, the RFC that obsoletes 822 (2822) is *also* obsolete, which shows you how out-of-date it is :) The current RFC for email addresses is 5322, published the month of this answer!

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address) includes an email validator.

There are plenty of regular expressions around for validating - everything from very basic to very advanced.
You really should pick something that matches the importance of a valid email in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to look at the source code of Zend_Validate_EmailAddress [[source](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php)].

Once you have your dependencies fixed, you can simply do the following:

```
$mail_validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
$mail_validator->isValid($address);   // returns true or false
```

The best would be to get the full Zend Library into your project via `svn external` and point the include path to it...

But you can just download the necessary files ([1](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php),[2](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Abstract.php),[3](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Ip.php),[4](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Interface.php),[5](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php),[6](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Loader.php)), and include them all (remove the *require_once* calls).

Comment: i tried but unfortunately its not working, i posted here aswell, can you help me please?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73750016/getting-error-while-using-zend-email-validation-php-fatal-error-uncaught-erro