# PHP - Email Validation

Tags: php, regex, email, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [email address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025466/email-address-validation)

Hello.
I have this function to validate an email address

```
function isValidEmail($email){
 return eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email);
}
```

It works well with domain zones like **.com**, **.us** etc, which contain from 2 to 3 symbols after a dot. My question is: is it important to include such zones as **.info** or **.travel** with length more than 3 symbols and should I worry about multiple  **.co.uk** etc.? How to improve the function for these needs?

Comment: 1. [`eregi` is deprecated](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) 2. yes, 3. use [`filter_var`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) 4. [it's a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+email+validation)

Answer (score 6):

there is a native function in php to do this, test it and see if it fits your needs:

```
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

P.S: Isn't `eregi()` deprecated?