# How do i validate that if new user doesn't enter ' @ ' on email, an error comes?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [email address validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025466/email-address-validation)

```
<?php

require_once('includes/inc_auth2.php');
require_once('includes/config.php');
//require_once('auth3.php');


    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {


        $title=$_POST['title'];
        $forename = $_POST['forename']; 
        $surname=$_POST ['surname'];
        $dob=$_POST ['dob'];
        $gender=$_POST ['gender'];
        $email=$_POST['email']; 
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $password=$_POST ['password'];


        if (authRegister($title, $forename, $surname, $dob, $gender, $email, $phone, $password))
        {
            echo 'Thank you for registering your details, you can now login'; 

            } 
            else
                {
                    outputErrors();
                    }



        if (empty($title))
            addError("Enter your title!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if (empty($forename))
            addError("Enter your name!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if (empty($surname))
            addError("Enter your surname!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if (empty($dob))
            addError("Enter your date of birth!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if ($gender == '0')
            addError("Enter your gender!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if (empty($email))
            addError("Enter your email!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

        if (empty($password))
            addError("Enter your password!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);

}

?>


<?=outputErrors()?>
 <div id="form_style">

   <form name="Create_Account" method="post" action="?page=register">

        <label> Title: </label>
            <select name="title" id="title">
             <option value="0">Select Title</option>
<?
        #
            foreach($titlesArray as $key => $value){

    // if title is selected 
            if ($title == $key)
            $selected = true; 
            else
            $selected = false; 

            echo '<option value="'.$key.'"';

            if($selected) 
            echo ' selected="selected"';

            echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    </select> 
 <br />


    <label>Forename:</label>
        <input name="forename" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['forename'])){  echo $forename; } ?>" /> <br />

    <label>Surname:</label>
        <input name="surname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['surname'])){  echo $surname; } ?>" /> <br />

    <label>Email:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){  echo $email; } ?>" /> <br />

            <label>phone:</label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email'])){  echo $email; } ?>" /> <br />

    <label>Password:</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password'])){  echo $password; } ?>" /> <br />

    <label>Confirm Password:</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['password'])){  echo $password; } ?>" /> <br />


    <label> Gender: </label>
        <select name="gender" id="gender">
        <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
        <?
        #
        foreach($gendersArray as $key => $value){

    // if gender is selected 
            if ($gender == $key)
            $selected = true; 
            else
            $selected = false; 

            echo '<option value="'.$key.'"';

            if($selected) 
            echo ' selected="selected"';

            echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            </select> 

           <br />


           <label>D.O.B  : </label>
            <input name="dob" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dob'])){  echo $dob; } ?>" /> <br/>

            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Register" class="button">
        </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To validate email addresses it is far better to use the native [PHP filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) and in particular the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) (linked) validate filter.

For example:

```
if (empty($email) or !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    addError("Enter your email!",LEVEL_CUSTOMER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(strpos($email, "@") === false) {
    addError("Email is invalid!", LEVEL_CUSTOMER);
}
```

For your other question, change the name of the confirm password box so that it is unique, like this:

```
<input type="password" name="password"...
<input type="password" name="password2"...
```

and then in your validation:

```
if($password != $password2) {
    addError("Passwords do not match!", LEVEL_CUSTOMER);
}
```

But passing your password field in plain text is not a good idea from a security standpoint.

Try validating your form using javascript before it is submitted, I made you an example here http://jsfiddle.net/dduncan/4GgTT/

Comment: Hi Dai, thatnk you very much for that, it worked perfect. How do i do the 'confirm password', i want the 'confirm password section to be able to see what has been entered in the original password field and match. If the password doesnt match, an error comes. Thanks

Comment: @Tawa, I updated my answer for you, don't ask me for any info on security as that isn't my area at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a simple validation for ex:

`^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$`

[link for Other secure ways to validate email with more examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Enjoy !