# Email validation in PHP

Tags: php, email-validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a php library for email address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

Hi there, I was just wondering if any of you use a particular public script or set of functions for dealing with email validation in PHP. The built-in PHP function isn't really anything to brag about.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation

Comment: What do you carp about the built-in functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to validate with cakephp function which can be found [here](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/validation/#line-488)

The regexp is this one:

```
'^[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:.[a-z0-9!#$%&*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?.)+(?:[a-z]{2,4}|museum|travel)$'
```

and can be found [here](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/validation/#l-41)

Comment: At the end it also excludes museum and travel?

Comment: No, it validates every 2-4 letter first-level domain (com, it, en, es, uk, org...) and the two long exceptions, .museum and .travel (which are first-level domains to, as shown http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain).

In simple words, museum and travel are the only two first-level domain longer than 4 char, so must be included.

Comment: Oh, didn't even know those existed. Thanks.