# Php script that test e-mail address

Tags: php, regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a php library for email address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)

How I can write php script that test e-mail address is input correctly and verify that the input begins with a series of character followed by the `@` character, another series of character and a final series of characters.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`filter_var()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function, using the [**`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter, should do exactly what you want -- no need to re-invent the wheel ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the PHP function [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var) with the [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/filter.filters.validate) flag to validate the email address:

```
$emailValid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if($emailValid) {
  echo "Email is valid";
} else {
  echo "Email is INVALID";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I mostly use `filter_var` for this, but a fellow github'r notified me that [this function is flawed](https://github.com/Znarkus/postmark-php/issues/3).

He recommended to use the rather more complex validator at http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if(preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",$email){
      $inputcorrectly = true; // Or whatever 
}

Comment: -1: Don't use regular expressions to validate email addresses. The RFC email syntax is way to complicated for a regular expression to handle properly.

Comment: Ah, OK. You learn something new every day, thanks! :D

Comment: @AndrewMoore: You do realize that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL uses a regex?