# regex that matches email addresses with address tags

Tags: regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a php library for email address validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161342/is-there-a-php-library-for-email-address-validation)
>   [How to validate an email in php5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855811/how-to-validate-an-email-in-php5)

I am aware that there have been plenty of questions regarding email address regular expressions.  My question has a specific requirement that I have been unable to find the answer to.

I need a regex that matches email addressas **and allows for [address tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags)**, such as "testing+tags@gmail.com".  Most regexes I have found fail on email addresses that contain a tag.

**NOTE** please do not point me to [this link](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).  I am looking for something practical, not perfect

**EDIT**  I am aware of the existence of built-in validation in most web app frameworks.  RoR, PHP, Django, etc all have it built in.  Sometimes, though, for whatever reason, there is a special need.  Maybe the user can't use validation.  maybe they are writing their app in some obscure language that doesn't have built-in validation functions, or has them, but they are out of date.  In that case, a regular expression is still useful

Comment: @SLaks That regex is so greedy it's in danger of eating StackOverflow whole... :-P

Comment: Well, not particularly wrong, but it needs a lot of discussion: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) - The outcome is not particularly practically feasible.

Comment: @ewok if so, please remove PHP tag...

Comment: Your edit makes this an invalid question. SO is for practical questions to problems you face. "What if for some reason in some language" isn't a valid question here. The answer in PHP is the built in function, not a regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My personal favorite has always been this:

```
/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Another popular one is also

```
/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/
```

If you are doing this in PHP and if feasible for your problem, I would suggest using [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/filter_var) as otherwise suggested.  This is merely a suggestion should you *need* a regular expression that is practical and understood to be imperfect.

Comment: `preg_match('[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+', 'bob+test@example.com', $matches1);` produces `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '+'`

Comment: @ewok Odd, I use `/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i` all the time. Did I typo?

Comment: perhaps.  the regex in the comment works properly.  the invalid identifier is a bit strange.  either way, edit the answer and the check is yours

Comment: this is sad... @ngmiceli (not your answer)

Comment: @webarto (and downvoters) Though I am no PHP guru, I would agree that `filter_var` is often be a better way to go. However, I am one to answer the OP question as it was written. Perhaps they have a perfectly good reason for needing a regex

Comment: I would rather say: regex is NOT the way to go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Comment: The regex in your answer will fail in some cases. This answer should not be used as a reference for how to solve this question.

Comment: @Caleb "I am looking for something practical, not perfect". As I said in meta, *verbatim*.

Comment: Doing this the right way is very simple and practical. If being flawed was part of the requirements for answers that would be different, but in general usage that phrase would imply they were willing to accept flaws if it made for a more practical solution. In this case there is no need for that.

Comment: @Caleb Well said; I respect that. To be fair but pedantic, the reference to `php` and its tag *were* removed from the question ;)

Comment: Also ask you need to do to fix this and stop collecting complaints from rabid programmers is to add a note about the best solution, why regex is problematic and then add whatever regex details you like...

Answer (score 8):

You <strike>could</strike> **should** use [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to validate email instead

```
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```

Example for your case:

```
echo filter_var('bob+long@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false? 'Valid': 'Invalid';
```

Comment: This is the only valid answer when it comes to email validation and PHP, don't use your own regexp, you will fail.

Comment: @webarto regardless, the question did not ask "what is the best way to validate email addresses", it asked "what is a regex that works well for validating email addresses with address tags"

Comment: @ewok this is a community, don't be selfish.

Comment: @webarto I wasnt trying to be selfish.  I was pointing out why A) this is not the accepted answer and B) I don't think ngmiceli should be getting downvotes.  he answered the question that was asked