# getting error while using zend email validation:: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator'

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to validate email while registration to makesure no spam.
For that purpose i learn that, Zend FrameWork is good for this.

So to try that following steps i followed:

1. i downloaded **ZendFramework-2.4.13.zip** from https://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives
2. I extract in the same path of my file and rename folder to **ZendFramework**
3. Then i try following code, as guided in their tutorial.

```
    require_once("ZendFramework/library/Zend/Validator/EmailAddress.php");
    
    $validator = new Zend\Validator\EmailAddress();
    $email = "mohibxxx@gmail.com";
    if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
        echo "Valid \n";
    } else {
        // email is invalid; print the reasons
        foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
            echo "$message\n";
        }
    }
```

But when i am running code, i got following error, i even checked the zend source class, but it seems normal.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator' not found in /home/account_name/public_html/test_mail/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Validator/EmailAddress.php:12

> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/account_name/public_html/test_mail/email-test.php(2): require_once()

> #1 {main}
> thrown in /home/account_name/public_html/test_mail/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Validator/EmailAddress.php on line 12

**Need experts help, what i am doing wrong, do i need to only call it by extending class?**

***Update***
I also tried following, **but still same error**

```
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/home/account_name/public_html/test_mail/ZendFramework/library/');
require_once("Zend/Validator/EmailAddress.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend using Composer to handle your dependencies, and its autoloader to handle loading classes. Life is much simpler that way.

Assuming that you have installed components with `composer require ...`, and assuming that you've followed the normal directory layout for a Laminas/Zend Framework 2 applications, then you just include the following in your `index.php` file:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'
```

It should be as simple as that: classes will be loaded without you having to `require` the individual files. If you make any changes to the `autoload` section in `composer.json`, make sure to dump the autoloader configuration again:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Also, Zend Framework has been replaced by Laminas; Zend Framework is no longer maintained, so you're missing out on bug fixes, security patches and new features. Laminas documentation is [here](https://docs.laminas.dev/): you'll want Laminas MVC and Laminas Components.

Comment: yes but i dont found much details about Laminas usage, so i thought its better that i first try Zend Framework.

Comment: and its autoloader to handle loading classes. Life is much simpler that way:: Can you guide me for that by giving an example, please?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you more details - I hope this helps.